# How to use VectorDrawables in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, android-vectordrawable

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to create a Xamarin Forms application that supports Android and iOS. I am new to Xamarin.

I would like to use scalable images on both platforms. I am starting with the Android side, and I want to use the newer VectorDrawable format.

Is it possible to use the native VectorDrawable support (with backward compatibility provided by the AppCompat library) in a Xamarin Forms app?

I have seen solutions that use svg images, and other rendering libraries, but I would like to know if I am missing something regarding Xamarin Forms before I go down an alternate road.

Comment: Check this answer [How to use Vector Drawables with Image element on Android?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/285590/#Comment_285590)

Comment: @TheDarkSeeker: I have seen that answer. I guess it kind of answers my question as stated. However, I was looking for more of a 'golden path' kind of answer, where you would layout controls normally in xaml, and have those controls use the scalable assets on either platform. The answer doesn't use xaml, and hits the layout aspects with a hammer (not necessarily bad). I was trying to find something more straightforward if it exists.

Comment: Mmmm... look at this then [Cross-Platform Images in Xamarin.Forms Using SVGs](https://www.patridgedev.com/2016/03/17/cross-platform-images-in-xamarin-forms-using-svgs/)

Comment: @TheDarkSeeker: Thanks for your comments. I have seen that link also, and I am leaning toward using that if no better option presents itself. It may be messier and rely on third party libraries when compared to your first link, but has the advantage of being able to share the svg assets across platforms. So far, it seems that the answer to my question is really "there is no built-in way to use scalable images on both iOS and Android". You must choose a work-around.

Comment: Yes, it's seems that this can't be handled from xamarin forms, try create a post in [Xamarin Forms Evolution Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/categories/xamarin-forms-evolution) to request this feature to be included in next releases :)